# Iterating Through ViewBag Strings, then populating a form with them

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

So I'm using ASP.NET and MVC and trying to take a list of strings and populate a form with them. Essentially, someone should be able to import account numbers, populate a form with them, and then hit the submit button. I've got the strings, and transferring them over using ViewBag, (I've tried this with ViewData and TempData as well) like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    String Path = @“C:\Users\a584619\testdata.xlsx”;
    String SheetName = “Sheet1”;
    DataReader dr = new DataReader();
    List<String> data = dr.readExcelFile(SheetName,Path);

    ViewBag.ExcelSSNS = data;

    return View();

}
```

Here's the html code. Me trying to Iterate through the items, and sneaking in some javascript between the Razor code so as to populate the form.

```
<script>
function getExcelSSNs(){
@foreach (string s in ViewBag.ExcelSSNs)
{
       <text>
document.getElementById(“ActInput”).value = @s + “\n"
       </text>
    }
}
```

I can see in the Chrome debugger that it's creating a document.getElementById etc. for every string in the List, and subsequently setting it but ideally I'd see a populated list of account numbers in the form for the user to submit. It's possible there's something wrong with the actual form, so I've included that here as well.

```
<div id = “input”>

<form>
    <input type = “text” id = “Actinput” class = “form-control” placeholder = “Paste/Import Here” required style = “ display : table; height : 45h; resize: none; border-radius: 0px; overflow-y: scroll”>
</form>
</input>
```

Any guidance here would be really appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: just a comment. I've noticed that "ActInput" in the html and "Actinput" in the form. That was an error in my inputing the code here, and is not reflected in the actual code. So that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do. Does the form have many inputs or just one? If it's just one, like it seems from the code you pasted here, note that this line

```
document.getElementById(“ActInput”).value = @s + “\n"
```

repeated many times in your @foreach 1) it doesn't include the necessary semi-column at the end of the statement and 2) will just replace the same input value over and over, which I don't think is what you need.

Also, your Html should be:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ActInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste/Import Here" style="display: table; height: 45px; resize: none; border-radius: 0px; overflow-y: scroll" required/>
</form>
```

You closed the input in the wrong way and the id was "Actinput" instead of "ActInput"

Comment: Yes you're understanding my problem. However, the issue is more about populating the input form. I can use Razor (ViewBag,Model., ViewDatat and TempData) all of them successfully transmit the list of Strings to the view - no problem. 

The problem then becomes populating the form. It doesn't like mixing razor and javascipt (should be noted that currently, I'm getting a syntax error, but it still runs).  Currently trying use the <text> brackets to clearly show that I'm using javascript, but it's not populating.

Comment: so I'm thinking that even if I had one long string, it still would not populate as I cannot access the form, no ?

Comment: So i've added that semi-colon and it actually did solve my synatx error (thank you). With the the html, I've actually changed it to a <textarea> as it's giving me behavior closer to what I want. But it's still not populating. I put in a list of strings and it populates the box with a random # I can't make out. "-1504" for example. It's not a truncated section of a String and it's not the result of any arithmetic as far as I can tell (they're strings after all). Cant figure it out.

Comment: would you update your question, maybe adding an updated version of your code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/?